# How to add data to a newly created column in migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, seed

In an already-deployed application, in my `seeds.rb`, I have the following:

```
State.create!(:state => "Alabama")
State.create!(:state => "Delaware")
...
```

Now I wanted to add the two-letter code for each state.

So I made a migration like this:

```
class AddStateCodeToStates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :states, :state_code, :string

    update(<<-SQL
    UPDATE states SET state_code='WA' where state = 'Washington'
    SQL
    )
    ...lots of these SQL statement...
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

**Problem is:**

In development environment, when I want to recreate the database from scratch, then after the migrations run, at that point the `seeds.rb` has not yet been run.

So, the `UPDATE xxx` in the `AddStateCodeToStates` migration has no data to work with (`states` table is empty because the data will be populated from the `seeds.rb`), thus the `state_code` remains `NULL`.

So my questions are (they are so related, so sorry for not asking them as each separate question):

1. How do I populate the `state_codes` when recreating the database (after the `states` table has data in it)?
2. How do I get the `state_codes` when `rake db:migrate` on the deployed app (`seeds.rb` does not run on `rake db:migrate`)
3. Should I not have used `seeds.rb` in the first place (and instead put data into the migrations)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like many things in Rails, you have many options, but.... general practice is to put necessary application data in `seeds.rb`.  You should write seeds.rb in a way that it can be run multiple times without adding extra records, e.g.

`State.find_or_create_by_state(:state => 'state_name_here', ':state_code => 'code here')`